# How to swap values in columns SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have table ( id , text) and I need to swap two values in columns like this:

```
Before. 
           1 one. 
           2 two.
           3 three.

After ( 1 and 3 swap)          
           1 three 
           2 two
           3 one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update each row, you need something like this:

```
void updateMyTableText (MyTableRow row)
{
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put ("text", MyTableRow.text);

  String where = "id = ?";
  String[] whereArgs = new String[1];
  whereArgs[0] = Long.toString (row.id);

  getDb().update ("MyTable", values, where, whereArgs);
}
```

where MyTableRow is

```
class MyTableRow
{
  long id;
  String text;
}
```

You'll also need some queries to get the "text" for rows 1 and 3.

Here's one way to do a query:

```
long getId (String text)
{
  // do the query
  String query = "select id from MyTable where text = ? ";
  String[] args = new String[1];
  args[0] = text;
  Cursor cursor = getDb().rawQuery (query, args);
  if (cursor == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException ("cursor is null");

  try
  {
    // get the results
    if (!cursor.moveToNext())
      return -1; // row not found

    long id = cursor.getLong (0);
    return id;
  }
  finally
  {
    cursor.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve id from db if i have both values text?

Comment: Good to hear it works.  I also updated the example to show how to do a query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the values in the rows themselves? Most databases systems don't let you arbitrarily swap values since there is an assumption that they are permanently associated. You could issue UPDATE commands to permanently modify the values, but doing this temporarily will probably be an issue handled once the data is returned.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET text=three
WHERE id=1;

UPDATE table_name
SET text=one
WHERE id=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming id1 < id2

void swap(id1,id2)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        ContentValues CV = new ContentValues();

        // First get the 2 rows
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE ID IN ("+id1+","+id2+") ORDER BY ID ASC",null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        CV.put("COLUMN_NAME",res.getString(0));
        //Update 1st row with 2nd item
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,CV,"ID = ?",new String[]{id2+""});
        res.moveToNext();
        CV.put("COLUMN_NAME",res.getString(0));
        //Update 2nd row with 1st item
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,CV,"ID = ?",new String[]{id1+""});
}
```

###### Hope it helps!!